# How to connect from client using CCDT and SSL to Remote Queue Manager (WebSphere MQ Server) using C#

Tags: c#-4.0, certificate, ssl-certificate, keystore, client-certificates

I am fairly new to the IBM WebSphere MQ.

And my requirement (as below) :

1) I want to create and configure Client Certificate, Server Certificate, Certificate Request, Certificate Authority, Key Stores using KeyType as CMS.

2) After the above, I need to configure Remote Queue Manager for SSL (TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256)

2) I will be using C#.NET code to connect using the CCDT Method.

I am looking for sample program(s) for the above if any.

Thanks & Regards, 
KJK

Answer (score 1):

i assumed you already have your CCDT file , So sample code

```
public void TestSSLConnectionWithCCDT()
        {
            try
            {
                Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MQCHLLIB", @"D:\MQCCDT\QM_SSLConnect\");
                Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MQCHLTAB", "AMQCLCHL.TAB");

                Hashtable props = new Hashtable();
                props.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT);
                props.Add(MQC.SSL_CERT_STORE_PROPERTY, sslKeyRepository);
                MQQueueManager qMgr = new MQQueueManager("QM_SSLConnect", props);

                MQQueue queue1 = qMgr.AccessQueue("XYZ", MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT | MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING);
                MQMessage msg = new MQMessage();
                msg.WriteUTF("Test Message");
                queue1.Put(msg);
            }
            catch (MQException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("WebSphere MQ error occurred: {0}", ex.ToString());
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("System error occurred: {0}", ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

You can test Transport level security with self-signed certificates, For more details follow the link http://2freeclear.wordpress.com/2014/11/29/transport-level-security-with-ibm-websphere-mq-in-net-environment/